# Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) when trying to delete 2 cloned objects

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am a person practicing C ++ code.
I have created an pointer DB1 of class DB and cloned it with another pointer DB2. I then tried to free up memory at the end of the program. I tried to delete DB1 and DB2, but when removing these 2 pointers, I encountered expression: "Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)". But if I just delete only DB1 or DB2 then the code can compile normally, but it leaks memory.

This is my code:

"Header.h"

```
class Le
{
protected:
    double* d = new double;
public:
    Le()
    {
        *d = 10.4;
    }
    Le(const Le& obj)
    {
        d = obj.d;
    }
    Le* clone() const
    {
        return new Le(*this);
    }
    virtual bool IsLe()
    {
        return true;
    }
    virtual ~Le()
    {
        delete d;
    }
};

class Huyen : public Le
{
    vector <int*>V;
public:
    Huyen()
    {
        for (int i = 0; (i) < 5; (i)++)
        {
            int* a = new int(i);
            V.push_back(a);
        }
    }
    Huyen(const Huyen& obj) : Le(obj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.V.size(); i++)
        {
            V.push_back(obj.V[i]);
        }
    }
    Huyen* clone()const
    {
        return new Huyen(*this);
    }
    bool IsLe()
    {
        return false;
    }
    ~Huyen()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        {
            delete V[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
        {
            V.pop_back();
        }
        V.shrink_to_fit();
    }
};
```

And "Source.cpp":

```
class DB
{
public:
    list<Le*>db;
    DB()
    {
        db.push_back(new Le());
        db.push_back(new Huyen());
    }
    DB(const DB& obj)
    {
        for (Le* p2 : obj.db)
        {
            if (p2->IsLe() == true)
            {
                db.push_back((*p2).clone());
            }
            else
            {
                Huyen* point = (Huyen*)p2;
                db.push_back((*point).clone());
            }
        }
    }
    DB* copy()
    {
        return new DB(*this);
    }
    ~DB()
    {
        for (list<Le*>::iterator p = db.begin(); p != db.end(); ++p)
        {
            delete* p;
        }
        db.clear();
        cout << "DB destructor \n";
    }
};

DB* DB1 = new DB;
DB* DB2 = NULL;
void CopyDB()
{
    DB2 = new DB(*DB1);
}
void ClearData()
{
    delete DB1;
    delete DB2; //problem will happen if I delete both DB1 and DB2, but if only delete DB1 or DB2 then no problem but memory leak

//check for memory leaks---------------------------------
HANDLE hLogFile;
hLogFile = CreateFile("log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, hLogFile);
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
CloseHandle(hLogFile);
//-------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Can someone show me how to be able to delete both DB1 and DB2 or not leak memory?
Thanks!

Comment: Broken copy constructor, it copies the pointer instead of the value.  So the destructor tries to delete a pointer that was (likely) already deleted.

Comment: Do you have any idea to change the constructor? I have tried it and can't figure out how to change the copy constructor. Probably because I'm a newbie and not inexperienced @HansPassant